# Grammatik von "Hallo zusammen"

Tags: grammar-identification

In der Anrede "Hallo zusammen", um welche Wortarten handelt es sich denn bei "Hallo" und bei "zusammen"?

Comment: Das lässt sich leicht durch Nachschauen in einem Wörterbuch ermitteln, z.B. https://www.dwds.de/wb/hallo und https://www.dwds.de/wb/zusammen. Daher würde ich die Frage als *off-topic* schließen.

Comment: Ich finde die Antwort auf die Frage keineswegs trivial. Als Muttersprachler ist mir nicht klar, wieso man an "Hallo" ein "zusammen" hängen darf und dadurch einen sinnvollen Gruß erhält. (Mein Verständnis ist, dass es sich um ein verkürztes "Hallo allen zusammen" handelt.)

Comment: *Im Prinzip* darf man mit einer Interjektion **alles**. Es ist ja schließlich ein (relativ zusammenhangloser) Ausruf, der nicht "normalen Satzbauregeln" unterliegt (Die meisten Leute denken nicht an ordentliche Grammatik, wenn ihnen z.B. grade ein Bleiklotz auf den Fuss gefallen ist und sie Bedarf für eine deftige Interjektion spüren). - Zugegeben, bei einem Gruß ist das ein bißchen anders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hallo* ist eine **Interjektion**

*zusammen* ist ein **Adverb**